# What exactly does this statement mean stack<int, list<int> > and how is it different from stack<int>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand what that `list<int>` does while we declare the stack `stack<int, list<int> >`. It does not change the from what I tried.

Comment: Is that `std::stack`? If so, start by reading the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Comment: Yes, std::stack and std::list
I actually use using namespace std :P

Answer (score 6):

[`stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) isn't a container, it's a *container adapter*. You tell it what type of element to store and what container to store it in.

It looks roughly like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T>>
class stack {
protected:
    Container c;
public:
    void push(T const& v) { c.push_back(v); }
    void pop() { c.pop_back(); }
};
```

As you can see, when you change from `stack<int>` to `stack<int, list<int>>`, you're just changing the underlying container storage. The interface doesn't change at all. But the performance *definitely* will - `deque` is a *much* better choice for a `stack` than `list` is...

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the answer. The standard containers std::vector, std::deque and std::list satisfy these requirements. By default, if no container class is specified for a particular stack class instantiation, the standard container std::deque is used.

Answer (score 0):

As described on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack, the second template parameter defines the underlying Container:

> Container     -   The type of the underlying container to use to store the
>   elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of
>   SequenceContainer. Additionally, it must provide the following
>   functions with the usual semantics:
>
> ```
> back()
> push_back()
> pop_back()
> ```
>
> The standard containers std::vector, std::deque and std::list satisfy
>   these requirements. By default, if no container class is specified for
>   a particular stack class instantiation, the standard container
>   std::deque is used.

So `std::stack<int, std::list<int> >` defines this stack to use a `std::list` as underlying container, instead of the default of `std::deque`